# Why didn't The Galactic Republic clone The Bad Batch (Clone Force 99)?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

Just look at how effective The Bad Batch was against the droids (maybe, even better than a Jedi):

I know that each clone is unique because of his unique experience and the environment he is exposed to (First episode of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* clearly shows different personalities of different clones), but here we are talking about mutations which indeed made clones better in certain fields as per canon.

> Experimental unit Clone Force 99, they're defective clones with, uh… desirable mutations.
>
> *-* Clone Commander CC-2224

Why didn't The Galactic Republic start cloning those units after discovering about them?

Comment: The base model clone seems to have performed well enough (given that they won the war), and the defective clones seemed rather rebellious in comparison. The advantages from the mutations might not have been worth potential problems associated with them.

Comment: also - remember, that the MAIN point of the clones wasn't to win an essentially fake war against droids. The 'regular' clones, care of the brain chips, would do their real job just fine

Comment: Could they "Execute Order 66", because that seems to be the end game of the clones. If they couldn't, the Supreme Chancellor probably wouldn't the creation of more...

Answer (score 4):

### TLDR - They got no chips and you get fewer clones.

One of the key features of the clone troopers employed by the Republic, and then the Empire, was that almost all clones had an *inhibitor chip* in their skulls which forced them to follow commands given to them, for example, **Order sixty six**.

What made Clone Force 99 unique was that they could operate in combat incredibly effectively without chips. The mutations that they had helped them in combat, but it would also have made the process of cloning more difficult for Kamino.

Let's take a real world example for a moment. Let's take the [Ford Model T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Model_T), one of the most widely produced cars of it's time, and do you know *why* it was the most widely produced car of all time? It's because it was simple to produce and the process was streamlined on a production line. There were no special bells and whistles, you got a car with four wheels, a seat and an engine. There were no variants which could have stripped down the overall number of cars that could have been built. If a variant was built, then fewer cars could be made as a whole production line would have to be devoted to producing that variant. The variant might be more expensive. You may have to get specised staff and machinery to run the production line. The same principle applies to why the Bad Batch were not cloned, it would have caused production issues and fewer clones would be able to be produced.

To add to this, if the kaminoans *did* want to produce more clones, they'd have to significantly invest in their infrastructure because, if it's not obvious to anyone watching the films or the *clone wars* TV series, they don't have much space:
[image: Kamino - also known as waterland]

As a sidenote the [series](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Bad_Batch) about this squad will be coming out at some point in the future and may hint at why the mutations were not made widespread among clones.

Comment: `They got no chips` ~> Do you have any citation?

Comment: @11.01.11 As of now I don't think there is anything that could serve as a citation, but The Bad Batch trailer shows clips from the upcoming show that appear to occur around the time of Order 66. It is likely that the new show will provide the evidence necessary to support this claim.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason they were so powerful was that they were fairly secret, so they could take the droid army by surprise. As you probably know, Echo (CT-1409) was taken by the Separatists and used to get information about the Republic, their tactics, etc. My guess is though, that the Bad Batch wasn’t included in that data.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to include some evidence to back up your claims?